# How to get specific checkbox function per row in a gridview C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, gridview

I am making a system that have many checkboxes per cell in a gridview. I want to be able to use individual functions for each of the checkboxes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUrq5.png)

For example, if the row 1 checkbox is checked, it will set the visible property of an object to true and the row 2 checkbox will do nothing.

This is my code for the OnRowCommand method of the gridview. It does not displayany error nor works as intended.

.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" class="table"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpName" HeaderText="Employee Name" >

                                <ControlStyle Height="30px" />
                                <ItemStyle Height="30px"`your text` />
                                </asp:BoundField>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Monday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblVisitMon" runat="server" Text="Visit"></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkMonday" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="SelectMon_OnCheckedChanged"/>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblPermitMon" runat="server" Text="Permit" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkWorkPermitMonday" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMon" runat="server" Visible="false">
                                            <asp:ListItem>SM Batangas</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>SM Bacoor</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
```

.cs

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row3 = (GridViewRow)(((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
            int requesitionID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            CheckBox mon = row3.FindControl("chkMonday") as CheckBox;

            if (mon.Checked)
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    var textbox = row.FindControl("lblPermitMon") as Label;
                    textbox.Visible = true;
                    var checkbox = row.FindControl("chkWorkPermitMonday") as CheckBox;
                    checkbox.Visible = true;
                    var ddl = row.FindControl("ddlMon") as DropDownList;
                    ddl.Visible = true;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Try and Add a `CommandField` to the GridView to generate a button for each row.
`<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to set the visibility of some controls in all rows of the GridView when the checkbox in a particular row is checked but you are not checking the specific row that triggered the OnRowCommand event. You need to check the specific row that triggered the event, and then set the visibility of the controls in that row accordingly.

so something like this;

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
    CheckBox mon = row.FindControl("chkMonday") as CheckBox;

    if (mon.Checked)
    {
        Label textbox = row.FindControl("lblPermitMon") as Label;
        textbox.Visible = true;
        CheckBox checkbox = row.FindControl("chkWorkPermitMonday") as CheckBox;
        checkbox.Visible = true;
        DropDownList ddl = row.FindControl("ddlMon") as DropDownList;
        ddl.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

let me know how this works for you.